# Position of horizontal flatlist item in relation to screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have a horizontal flatlist in my component, which renders cards. These cards have all the same width and height. When the user selects an item, I want to have the x and y coordinates of the specific item in relation to the screen.

I tried different suggested approaches from the docs, but they resulted only in getting the position in relation to the whole generated flatlist. I would want to have the coordinates, you are able to see, when you select the item through the style-inspector.

This is the code I'm using:
FlatlistParent:

```
<FlatList
    data={this.props.data}
    renderItem={this.renderItem}
    keyExtractor={item => item.key}
    horizontal={true}
    showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
    onScrollBeginDrag={this.horizontalScrollStarted}
    getItemLayout={(data, index) => (
    {length: itemWidth, offset: itemWidth * index, index}
)}/>
```

And renderItem()

```
      <View ref={ref => this.temp = ref} onLayout={this._onLayout}>
        <Animated.View style={[styles.hiddenChild, scaleStyle]}>
        </Animated.View>
        <PanGestureHandler
          onGestureEvent={_handleGesture}
          onHandlerStateChange={_handleStateChange}
          activeOffsetY={[-10, 10]}
          >
          <Animated.View style={[styles.shadow, translateStyle]}>
            <TouchableNativeFeedback onPress={() => this._onPressButton(item)} >
              <FastImage source={{uri: item.imagePath}} style={styles.item}/>
              <LinearGradient start={{x: 0, y: 1}} end={{x: 0, y: 0}} colors={["black", "#00000000"]} style={styles.linearGradient}></LinearGradient>
              <View style={styles.titleParent}>
                  <Text style={styles.title}>{item.title}</Text>
              </View>
            </TouchableNativeFeedback>
          </Animated.View>
        </PanGestureHandler>
      </View>
```

And this is, what I used to access the x and y coordinates of the item:

```
  _onLayout = ({ nativeEvent: { layout: { x, y }} }) => {
    this.secondTemp = [x, y]
  };

  _onPressButton(item) {
    this.temp.measure((x, y, pageX, pageY) => {
      console.log('#1 ' + x + ' ' + y + ' ' + pageX + ' ' + pageY)
      console.log('#2 ' + this.secondTemp)
    })

    this.temp.measureInWindow((x, y) => {
          console.log('#3 ' + x,y)
    })

    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    // navigate('RecipeDetail', item)
  }
```

The console Outputs are the following for moving the flatlist from the initial position a little bit and pressing button:

```
 LOG  #1 0 0
 LOG  #2 0,0
 LOG  #3 1272 0
___________
 LOG  #1 0 0
 LOG  #2 0,0
 LOG  #3 1201 0
___________
 LOG  #1 0 0
 LOG  #2 0,0
 LOG  #3 1145.75 0
```

I already tried putting the ref call on the image, no luck there. Also using measureLayout with a findNodeHandle to a parent view resulted in always getting the full 1272 as a x coordinate.

Any ideas, some help in which direction I have to go?

Comment: hey what you trying to do with your list item ?

Comment: @Prakash Karena, my list item holds an image. and I want to make a transition for this image on the detail screen, which should start from it's source position. therefore i need the coordinates of the image on my master view.

Comment: Did you solve this?